# JSF and JQuery  - doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jsf, netbeans

I am trying to get JQuery to work in JSF, but I haven't had success. The scripts are in the folder `resources`. I am using NetBeans.

This is my JSP code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
Document   : testpage
Created on : 08.07.2009, 01:16:01
Author     : reBourne 
-->
<jsp:root version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns:webuijsf="http://www.sun.com/webui/webuijsf">
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<f:view>
    <webuijsf:page id="page1">
        <webuijsf:html id="html1">
            <webuijsf:head id="head1">
                <webuijsf:link id="link1" url="/resources/css/stylesheet.css"/>
                <webuijsf:script id="script1" url="resources/jquery.js"/>
                <webuijsf:script id="script2" url="recources/main.js" />

<style>
body {
margin:0;
padding:40px;
background:#fff;
font:80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#555;
line-height:180%;
}

h1{
font-size:180%;
font-weight:normal;
color:#555;
}
h2{
clear:both;
font-size:160%;
font-weight:normal;
color:#555;
margin:0;
padding:.5em 0;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
color:#f30; 
}
p{
clear:both;
margin:0;
padding:.5em 0;
}
pre{
display:block;
font:100% "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #bae2f0;
background:#e3f4f9; 
margin:.5em 0;
overflow:auto;
width:800px;
}

img{border:none;}
ul,li{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
display:inline;
margin-right:10px;
}



 /*  */

#preview{
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #ccc;
background:#333;
padding:5px;
display:none;
color:#fff;
}

 /*  */
 </style>
            </webuijsf:head>
            <webuijsf:body id="body1" style="-rave-layout: grid">
                <webuijsf:form id="form1">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="preview" href="resources/images/1.jpg">
                                <img alt="gallery thumbnail" src="resources/images/1s.jpg"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="preview" href="resources/images/2.jpg">
                                <img alt="gallery thumbnail" src="resources/images/2s.jpg"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="preview" href="resources/images/3.jpg">
                                <img alt="gallery thumbnail" src="resources/images/3s.jpg"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="preview" href="resources/images/4.jpg">
                                <img alt="gallery thumbnail" src="resources/images/4s.jpg"/>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </webuijsf:form>
            </webuijsf:body>
        </webuijsf:html>
    </webuijsf:page>
</f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Does someone have a real life example with JavaScript?

Comment: Should it be url="/resources"?  What gets output for your script tag for jquery?

Answer (score 3):

AWW MAN .. i had a little typo :/

```
        <webuijsf:script id="script1" url="resources/jquery.js"/>
        <webuijsf:script id="script2" url="recources/main.js" />
```

it is reSources/main.js"  <-- there it is.

:/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery works fine with JSF, ust make sure you are using it correctly. From the jQuery website ([Using jQuery with other Libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)) you need to make sure to use jQuery.noConflict() or jQuery(...) instead of $(...).

For example, you can use the following to make sure jQuery doesn't clash with other libraries.

```
var $J = jQuery.noConflict();

$J(<selector>)...
```

If you are using RichFaces you can also check out it's support for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about best solution for $J = jQuery.noConflict();

Because,
I wrote code for print the textarea content using jQuery. 
Also i use rich:dataScroller tag in my jsp page..

Two scenario occur :

One, Printing work, But rich:dataScroller not work (Without using **jQuery.noConflict()**)

Second, Printing not work, rich:dataScroller working (Using **jQuery.noConflict()**)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902374/how-to-integrate-jquery-with-jsf-richfaces-tags-for-print-the-image-and-textarea